# List column is deleted when updating Content Type using web services

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint-2010

I have a large collection of sites that all use the copies of the same content type.  I'm using the web service and calling the updateContentType methods from either webs.asmx or lists.asmx.  Code below:

```
contentProps = "<ContentType />";
newField, modField = "<Fields />";
delField = "<Fields>" +
             "<Method ID=\"1\">" +
               "<Field ID=\"fieldID\" />" +
             "</Method>" + 
           "</Fields>";
//...Snip XmlDocument.LoadXml() to create the proper XmlNodes
listSvc.UpdateContentType(listName,contentID,contentProps,newField,modField,delField,"true"); or
webSvc.UpdateConentType(contentID,contentProps,newField,modField,delField);
```

The field is deleted from the Content Type as well as the column from the List.  I only want to remove it from the Content Type, but retain the column in the list.  All the documentation I've read only specify the field is removed from the ContentType not the list itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint automatically updates all the lists using a content type when the content type changes, the only scenario where this does not apply is when the content type is a site content type applied to the list and the site content type is deployed using a SharePoint feature. 
To readup more on this check out the following links:

1. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms463016%28v=office.14%29.aspx)
2. [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446451/sharepoint-what-happens-to-lists-based-on-content-type-when-content-type-is-upd)

Comment: Thanks for the links.  I guess I will need to go modify each site manually.